# row aggregation according to date in R and sum corresponding other column values divided by number of aggregated rows

Tags: r, aggregate

Below is a part of my rather large table called "input":

```
        [,1]     [,2]   [,3]             
[7146,] 20100324 7.70   4.0000000
[7147,] 20100324 2.22   0.0000000
[7148,] 20100325 2.12   0.0000000
[7149,] 20100326 2.29   0.0000000
[7150,] 20100327 2.10   0.0000000
[7151,] 20100328 2.26   2.0000000
[7152,] 20100328 2.01   1.6000000
[7153,] 20100328 2.17   0.0000000
[7154,] 20100329 1.92   0.0000000
[7155,] 20100330 2.15   0.0000000
```

What I am trying to do is as follows:

I want to aggregate the rows that have the same date (dates are stated in column [,1]) and sum the values of these rows in columns [,2] and [,3] divided by the number of rows that are aggregated.

The output would be something like this:

```
        [,1]  [,2]   [,3]             
[1,] 20100324 4.96   2.0000000 # e.g: [1,2] = (input[7146,2] + input[7147,2])/2 = (7.70 
[2,] 20100325 2.12   0.0000000                + 2.22)/2 = 4.96 
[3,] 20100326 2.29   0.0000000
[4,] 20100327 2.10   0.0000000
[5,] 20100328 2.15   1.2000000
[6,] 20100329 1.92   0.0000000
[7,] 20100330 2.15   0.0000000
```

Help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sampla data

```
df<-read.table(text="           
 20100324 7.70   4.0000000
 20100324 2.22   0.0000000
 20100325 2.12   0.0000000
 20100326 2.29   0.0000000
 20100327 2.10   0.0000000
 20100328 2.26   2.0000000
 20100328 2.01   1.6000000
 20100328 2.17   0.0000000
 20100329 1.92   0.0000000
 20100330 2.15   0.0000000")
```

One way is to use function `ddply()` and then calculate `colMeans()` for each column except first, that is used to split data.

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df,.(V1),colMeans)
        V1       V2  V3
1 20100324 4.960000 2.0
2 20100325 2.120000 0.0
3 20100326 2.290000 0.0
4 20100327 2.100000 0.0
5 20100328 2.146667 1.2
6 20100329 1.920000 0.0
7 20100330 2.150000 0.0
```

The same result can be achieved with `aggregate()`.

```
aggregate(.~V1,data=df,mean)
        V1       V2  V3
1 20100324 4.960000 2.0
2 20100325 2.120000 0.0
3 20100326 2.290000 0.0
4 20100327 2.100000 0.0
5 20100328 2.146667 1.2
6 20100329 1.920000 0.0
7 20100330 2.150000 0.0
```

Third options is to use advantages of package `data.table`, especially if you have large data frame.

```
 library(data.table)
#Convert your data frame to data table and set column V1 as key.
 dt<-data.table(df,key="V1")
#Calculate mean for each column .SD means subset of your data table
 dt[,lapply(.SD,mean),by=V1]
         V1       V2  V3
1: 20100324 4.960000 2.0
2: 20100325 2.120000 0.0
3: 20100326 2.290000 0.0
4: 20100327 2.100000 0.0
5: 20100328 2.146667 1.2
6: 20100329 1.920000 0.0
7: 20100330 2.150000 0.0
```

Comment: Thx for the respons! I still have one problem though. I cannot use the function: df<-read.table(text=""), because i cannot copy the entire table in R since it is to big. And when I insert: "input" instead of "df" and "input[,1]" in the ddply function instead of "V1" as shown shown:  "ddply(input,.(input[,1]),colMeans)", I get the following error:
Error in eval.quoted(.variables, data) : 
  envir must be either NULL, a list, or an environment.

Comment: This line was just the way I put your data in my R session. Instead of df, use real name of your data frame and real names of columns.

Comment: Else you can convert your matrix to data.frame to use solutions provided above.

Comment: Thats it! Works now. Had to convert matrix to data.frame. Thanks a lot for the help!